# Talk to/with me

Tags: word-choice, sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language

*I just want to know what I've done since you suddenly don't want to talk to me anymore.*

Is "...talk **to** me..." natural if my intention with the sentence is this: "...since you suddenly don't want to have a conversation with me anymore." and not "...since you suddenly don't want to say a word to me anymore." Or should I use "**with**" instead?

Comment: Both are correct. Given the human psychology, they will not misinterpret the meaning of the sentence, whether you use "to" or "with".

Comment: In my experience, **talk with** is more common in N America; **talk to** is more common in the UK. Google Books Ngram Viewer indicates that **talk to** has historically been far more popular. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&smoothing=3&content=talk+to%2Ctalk+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctalk%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctalk%20with%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

Broadly, both are interchangeable. However, if you still want to dig it deeper, I'd give *my* choice/preference.

> *talk to someone*

is more kind of monologue where you speak more and whom you are *talking **to*** listens more.

On the other hand,

> *talk with someone*

is a kind of dialogue between two where both almost equally participate.

To elaborate, let me think of an example -

I'm a team leader and if *A* from my team comes and 'complains' about *B,* I may say,

> *Okay, I'll talk to B.*

What I mean is I'll *raise* the issue and probably instruct *B* not to do such things in future. Mostly, I'll speak and *B* will listen.

However, if my boss calls me and asks to implement some new strategies across the teams, I'd probably say,

> *Okay, I'll speak with my team members.*

It'll have a fruitful discussion probably each one of my team will participate and give their inputs.

But, as I said earlier, largely, both are interchangeable with no *big* difference in most of the cases.